# Is value for ALT atrribute not required in HTML5 to pass validation?

Tags: html, accessibility

I was looking at this Slideshow http://www.slideshare.net/CharJTF/structures-semantics-controls-and-more-html-5-is-here-3523971 and on slide #14 there are 3 examples of img tag

**third one is without value. Is it allow in HTML 5?**

[image]

Comment: Your question title and question body do not appear to be at all related to each other. What question are you trying to ask?

Comment: Sorry i mistakenly posted with wrong body. now it's ok

Comment: @ben - I think you commented in wrong question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [parsing rules for attributes start here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tokenization.html#before-attribute-name-state).  Note that the default action on encountering the first character of an attribute is this:

> Start a new attribute in the current tag token. Set that attribute's
>   name to the current input character, and its value to the empty
>   string. Switch to the attribute name state.

So in HTML5, `alt` and `alt=""` are equivalent.

It is acceptable to have an empty string value for an `alt` attribute when the image is entirely presentational (though really in that case, that image should be included with CSS rather than in the content), or when it would repeat information already available to the detriment of screen reader users.  The point of putting an empty string there instead of leaving off altogether is that many screenreaders, if there isn't an `alt` attribute, will read out the full path in the `src` attribute instead.

Comment: Do note, that although the answer to this question is correct in context to empty alt discussion, the image provided above indicates a 207 by 47 bitmap, which is unlikely to be for decoration or layout purposes only. I'm simply stating the last line might be a bad example for the uninitiated!

Answer (score 2):

[HTML 5 now defines](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-attributes) `foo` as being the same as `foo=''`