# Alt atrribute missing in AMP WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, amp-html

I'm using official WordPress AMP plugin to create my custom WordPress theme. For images I use

```
<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()):?>
<img class="img2" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('blog-small'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title();?>">
<?php endif;?>
```

I get regular `alt` attribute as expected but the alt attribute is missing in some auto generated AMP codes. Here is an example of that code:

```
<img alt aria-hidden="true" class="i-amphtml-intrinsic-sizer" role="presentation" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBoZWlnaHQ9JzIxMCcgd2lkdGg9JzQwMCcgeG1sbnM9J2h0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnJyB2ZXJzaW9uPScxLjEnLz4=">
```

As you can see here the `alt` attribute do not contain any value. Can any one help me to solve the problem? I'm not looking for AMP validation. Missing alt can harm SEO. If you wish you can provide a code snippet so that I can understand it easily. (I'm a new coder)

Comment: an empty alt tag is a valid value. It looks like you want to show an icon. `aria-hidden` explains the screenreaders to ignore that image. so the alt attribute is (maybe) a valid point here too

Comment: I'm not using any icon. Bing search console is showing "Warning" for missing `alt` value. I'm confused :/

Comment: "warning" for missing `alt` value is not an error, in your particular case alt is given as empty for a particular reason as said by @Sysix

Comment: Are you confused that the `alt` attribute (not a tag!) doesn't contain any text, or just that it's spelled `alt` rather than `alt=""`? For the latter, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729918/is-value-for-alt-atrribute-not-required-in-html5-to-pass-validation

Comment: I'm confused that the alt attribute doesn't contain any text. Why its happening?

Comment: optimizing for bytes (speed)